# How to read Module federation remote entry from Angular service?

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

I use Module Federation in Angular app.
I need to load remote Entry dynamically from url which is pulled on APP_INITIALIZER from some API.
Its location is EnvironmentService.authUrl.

How to set remote entry url on runtime?

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        resolve: {
            data: DataResolver          
        },
        loadChildren: () =>
            loadRemoteModule({
                remoteName: 'authorization',
                // here, how to set it dynamically on runtime
                **remoteEntry**: environmentService.authUrl,
                exposedModule: 'AuthorizationModule'
            }).then((m) => m.AuthorizationModule)
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[canLoad]` guard and inside it get the remote entry url from your service and have it in some global variable. Then use the global variable as `remoteEntry : Global Variable` .

The beauty of `[canLoad]` is , it will enable the routing only after the service call finished. Remember to make the return type of `[canLoad]` as `of(boolean)`.